# MySQL query Find and Replace in Specific Columns in a Table?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to set all values in certain columns...to 1 (where they are now NULL)

Can anyone help out with a little assist on this SQL query/command syntax?

I need to replace several columns where the SchoolID is 184 with a 1, something like this?

SELECT * FROM `tblMembers` WHERE `SchoolID` SET `column` = '1';

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement:

```
UPDATE tblMembers 
SET column = '1'
WHERE SchoolID = '184'
```

You can set multiple columns at the same time:

```
UPDATE tblMembers 
SET column = '1', column2 = 'somethingelse', column3 = 'somethingelse'
WHERE SchoolID = '184'
```